# Catch ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique and all other exceptions after

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a uniqueness constraint in my LineItem model that looks like this :

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
    # this add uniqueness validation to [cart_id + product_id] together
    validates :cart_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:product_id] }
end
```

I added indexes + unique:true to these columns in my database as well for more security

In my `LineItemsController#create` I have the following

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

    def create 

        @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id]

        product = Product.find(params[:product_id]

        @line_item = @cart.add_product(product, params[:licence])

        respond_to do |format|

            @line_item.save!

            format.html { redirect_to products_url }
            format.js 

         rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique

          @cart.line_items
             .find_by(product_id: params[:product_id])
             .update(licence_type: params[:licence], price: product.price)

          format.js

        end

    end

end
```

What I am trying to do is : if the user add a line item that already has the same product_id and cart_id then update the licence_type column with params[:licence]

Am using `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` for this purpose :

1 - is this a good way to do it (so I can save my self an additional request that check every time if the record exists in the database) ?

2 - How I can catch any other exceptions/errors other than `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` ?  I thought to add another `rescue Exception => e` at the bottom so I can catch all other exception but I think I read somewhere that catching general exception like that isn't good and that I should use something like `rescue => e` instead ?

any code snippet is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Never rely on uniqueness validation](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations) to save you from duplicate data. It has a well-established weakness to race conditions.

What you probably want in this case is [`find_or_initialize_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by).

```
line_item = @cart.line_items.find_or_initialize_by(product_id: params[:product_id])
line_item.license_type = params[:license]
line_item.save
```

In addition to that, you should move the uniqueness constraint on this data into the DB. The specific way of doing that depends on what your DB is.

It's okay to keep the validator, but treat it like front-end validation; there as a convenience, to create a better user experience. But don't rely on it to keep your data consistent, that is the job of your DB.

---

Another comment on the code sample:

`rescue` has to be placed either within a `begin..end` block or as part of a method body. But in your case you have it inside of a `do..end` block without a surrounding `begin..end`, which will not work.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, I already mentioned in my post that I have added indexes to my DB level. I totally agree with you but what bother me a little is that actually I have 4 requests in total to create that line item, I updated my create method to be more clear : First I retrieve the cart, second I find the product by id (to get its price), third I check if the product exist already in the cart, 4th I save my record

Comment: my idea was that I can reduce the number of request to 3 or even less, so I tried to catch the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` which I found that it's triggered only when the database uniqueness constraint fails (and NOT when the Model Validation fails), so I thought maybe I can remove the validation from the model, and just rely on the database to raise the exception so I can catch it with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`

Comment: this at least allow to skip the request that check every time if the record exists in the database. but I would like to know if you have a better idea or thought about that?

Comment: @medBo multiple requests aren't _necessarily_ bad if they are fast. Have you verified this is a performance issue through profiling? In this case, assuming that your carts don't usually have a large number of line_items, I would just eager-load the product and line_items ahead of time.

Comment: no I haven't measured the performance I just try to minimize the number of requests as possible in all my developments :) I always have this felling that more requests means more "slow" more "bad user experience", but I will go with `find_or_initialize_by` it make my code more clean then before :D (eager loading the line_items won't do any benefit in my case because it will make an additional request anyway, and the product can't be eager loaded because I retrieve it by id to see its price and put that price in the line item)

Comment: @medBo it's good that you are thinking about keeping your request count down, but there are diminishing returns inherent to that.